# How to avoid multiple compatibility projects appcompat_v7

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time i create a new project with compatibility under API14, a new project with name `appcompat_v7_*` is created.

Is it possible to avoid the multiple creations of this `appcompat_v7_*` and use a single project `appcompat_v7` in other projects ?

*-> Number that increments with each new android project.